# Derivation of a fourier transfrom of a derivative multiplied by a linear function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

How can the following identity be derived
$$F\left\{\frac{d(xf(x))}{dx}\right\}=-k\frac{d\hat{f}(k)}{dk}$$

where
$$\hat{f}(k)=F\left\{f(x)\right\}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$

Comment: Maybe try integration by parts after plugging $xf(x)$ in the Fourier integral?

Comment: @mrtaurho, I've tried, it leads me nowhere. don't know how to handle the boundaries, and I still have a function that I can't define.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume here that $f$ is a continuous function such that $x\,f(x)\to0$ sufficiently quickly as $x\to\pm\infty$.  We have
$$\begin{align}
F\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\,\big(x\,f(x)\big)\right\}(k)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\int_{x=-\infty}^{x=+\infty}\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}\big(x\,f(x)\big)
\\
&=-\frac{k}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,(-\text{i}x)\,f(x)\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}x\,,
\end{align}$$
where we have applied the technique of integration by parts.  In this part, continuity of $f$ ensures that the integral $\int_{-R}^{+R}\,(-\text{i}x)\,f(x)\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}x$ can be evaluated at each $R>0$, and the condition that $x\,f(x)\to 0$ quickly as $|x|\to\infty$ guarantees that the limit of this integral as $R\to\infty$ exists and is finite for each $k$.

Next, observe that
$$\begin{align}
F\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\,\big(x\,f(x)\big)\right\}(k)&=-\frac{k}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,(-\text{i}x)\,f(x)\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}x\\
&=-\frac{k}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}k}\big(f(x)\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\big)\,\text{d}x
\\
&=-k\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}k}\,\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\,f(x)\,\exp(-\text{i}kx)\,\text{d}x\right)
\\&=-k\,\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}k}\,\hat{f}(k)\,,
\end{align}$$
where we have implemented [Leibniz Integral Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).  Continuity of $f$ means that the derivative commutes with the integral, and it also means that $\hat{f}$ is differentiable.

However, you may still have a meaningful question even if $f$ is not continuous (using weak derivatives instead) or does not vanish very quickly, but the Fourier transform can end up being a distribution (i.e., not a function).  Nonetheless, I am not certain which class of $f$ will be a good choice.

Comment: how did the variable of integration became $d(xf(x))$?

Comment: You have the differential form $\displaystyle\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\,\big(x\,f(x)\big)\right)\,\text{d}x$, which equals the differential form $\text{d}\big(x\,f(x)\big)$.

Comment: $\frac{\mathrm{d}(xf(x))}{\mathrm{d}x}\cdot\mathrm{d}x~=~\mathrm{d}(xf(x))$ I would suggest.

Comment: @Batominovski, thank you.